# Преобразование числа в строку в js

Tags: javascript, html, css, pagination, padding

Есть код, меняющий расположение пагинации и в нем число приводится к строке

```js
if (end - start < notesOnPage) {
  console.log('pagination version 1');
  pagination.style.paddingBottom = String($('.centerareawrapper').height - (end - start) * 195 - 41 - 40) + 'px';
  console.log(pagination.style.paddingBottom);
  console.log(String($('.centerareawrapper').height - (end - start) * 195 - 41 - 40) + 'px');
} else {
  console.log('pagination version 2');
  pagination.style.paddingBottom = '126px';
}
```

В результате при выводе в консоль строки

```
    console.log(String($('.centerareawrapper').height-(end-start)*195-41-40)+'px');
```

получаю `NaNpx`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У объекта jQuery нет свойства `height`, но есть одноименный метод.

```
$('.centerareawrapper').height() ...
                              ^^
```

Comment: плюс за ответ в виде кода с пояснениями.